# Arithmetic mean and geometric mean in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a probability space. I want to show if $f_1\in L^{p_1}(\mu),$ $f_2\in L^{p_2}(\mu)$, ... , $f_n\in L^{p_n}(\mu)$, then $$(f_1f_2\cdots f_n)^{\frac{1}{1/p_1+\dots+1/p_n}}\in L^1(\mu).$$ In particular, if $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}\subset L^1(\mu)$ then $\sqrt[n]{f_1\cdots f_n}\in L^1(\mu)$.

I think I can use the inequality of the arithmetic mean and geometric mean to conclude something of the form $$ \Big(\int_X |f_1\cdots f_n| \Big)^{\frac{1}{1/p_1+\dots+1/p_n}}\leq\prod_{i=1}^n\Big(\int_X (f_i)^{p_1}\Big)^{1/p_i}$$

Can anyone tell me if this the right way?
Greetings !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the generalised [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality): *If
$$
\frac{1}{p_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p_n}=1,
$$ 
and $f_1\in L^{p_1}(X),\ldots,f_n\in L^{p_n}(X)$, then $f_1f_2\cdots f_n\in L^1(X)$, and*
$$
\Big| \int_X f_1\cdots f_n\,dx\,\Big|\le \Big(\int_X \lvert\,f_1\rvert^{p_1}\Big)^{1/p_1}
\cdots \Big(\int_X \lvert\,f_n\rvert^{p_n}\Big)^{1/p_n}\!.
$$

If $\frac{1}{p_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p_n}=\frac{1}{a}\ne 1$, then 
$\frac{a}{p_1}+\cdots+\frac{a}{p_n}= 1$ 
and $\,\lvert\, f_i\rvert^{1/a}\in L^{p_i/a}$, and using the above we obtain that
$f_1f_2\cdots f_n\in L^a(X)$, and
$$
\Big| \int_X \lvert \,f_1\cdots f_n\rvert^a\,dx\,\Big|\le \Big(\int_X \lvert\,f_1\rvert^{p_1}\Big)^{a/p_1}
\cdots \Big(\int_X \lvert\,f_n\rvert^{p_n}\Big)^{a/p_n}\!.
$$
Note that
$$
a=\frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{p_1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{p_n}}.
$$

Comment: but, what happen if i can't asume that $\frac{1}{p_1}+\dots+\frac{1}{p_n}=1$?

Comment: See my edited answer.